# Create link with explicit title/text using console.log

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Is there a `console.log` or `console.error` way of logging customly-named links to the JS console of all modern browsers?

I'm thinking of something similar to an `<a href=...>Title goes here</a>` so that we don't have to log a really long link where a descriptive title would make much more sense.